# Utilizar Json en php

Tags: php, json

Buenas Tardes quisiera saber como puedo pasar datos obtenidos de api key web, que vienen serializados. Quiero pasarlos a tabla html.
Viene asi:

```
[{"Plate":"XC9888","Year":"2004"}]1
```

Answer (score 0):

Usa json_decode().
Cuando obtienes el contenido del documento viene en formato string. Con

```
json_decode($json_string);
```

Lo transforma en un array.
Para más información consulta [la api](http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php) por que ofrece bastantes opciones extra.

**Edito:** 
Ten muy en cuenta, que el json no acabe en "," porque me dio muchos quebraderos de cabeza en su día.

Ej:

```
{"Plate":"XC9888","Year":"2004"} // Así valdría

{"Plate":"XC9888","Year":"2004",} // Así daría error (o no saldría nada)
```

Comment: no aparece con json_decode. los datos son llamados con curl_exec, y vienen entre corchetes [{datos:ooo}]

Comment: Pero su formato es un string?

Comment: si pero no puedo obtenerlos en alguna variable

Comment: Prueba a eliminar el primer y último caracter (los corchetes "[]") e intenta hacer json_decode del string restante.

Answer (score 0):

Existe un parámetro si la API está en ASP.NET para quitar esos corchetes y mostrarla como PHP la puede leer y convertir en array, revisa el parámetro de formación del JSON de la API.

Ya en PHP puedes convertirlo a array con json_decode($json_string);

Y luego hacer un foreach para imprimir los rows de la tabla.